# Angular-redux design - array selector

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, observable, subscribe

I have angular application using Redux design pattern.
My state contains array of students. Each student has multiple attributes
name,age,id, etc..

I would like to select a specific student grade.

This is my component code

```
  @select('students')
  private students: Observable<any>;
```

Since I have the Id of the student, I could subscribe to the students observable and find my student. This is working but of course is not the best practice.

```
 this.students.subscribe(students => {
     const student = students[this.id];
    console.log(student);
   });
```

How can I access a specific student?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i did in the end was to update my select:

```
 @select(state => state.students .find(s => s.id=== state.ui.id))
  student: Observable<any>;
```

that why I can subscribe to a specific student